# Introducing: The Formatting Sandbox in the Middle of Nowhere

Tags: discussion

You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can

- Edit this question itself (Community Wiki questions such as this one require 100 reputation to edit)
- Post answers to this question (Since this question is protected requires 10 reputation)
- Post comments to this question or its answers

Comment: Is this some feature you want added?

Comment: @MiharuDante actuly i think it's more like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: I love this place <3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because

Comment: I do wonder thou Post answers to this question (Since this question is protected requires 10 reputation). Might just be me. But this ain't protected ;)

Comment: hmmm, what happen if someone unprotect this question if this question got protected by other user or mod or community, will the user who protected it got notification?

Comment: Testing comment filter: XXX is a repwhore.

Comment: Testing comment filter: XXX is a rep whore.

Comment: Testing comment filter: XXX is a rep whore just like you.

Comment: Testing comment filter: anon is a rep whore just like you.

Comment: @Mysticial you're the rep whore (just for testing, once again)

Comment: [Rep whore testing context](http://i.stack.imgur.com/74Z4Z.png)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Keyboard]

<kbd>Esc</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>  <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>   <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>
<kbd><sub>`</sub><sup>~</sup></kbd>   <kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>-</sub><sup>_</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>=</sub><sup>+</sup></kbd><kbd><- Backspace</kbd>
<kbd>Tab</kbd>    <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd><kbd><sub>[</sub><sup>{</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>]</sub><sup>}</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>\</sub><sup>|</sup></kbd>                 
<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd><sub>;</sub><sup>:</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>'</sub><sup>"</sup></kbd><kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>            
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>           <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd><sub>,</sub><sup><</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>.</sub><sup>></sup></kbd><kbd><sub>/</sub><sup>?</sup></kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>                  

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>         <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>                                           <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>????</kbd>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

[image]

<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>

Partional keyboard, got lazy XD

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>**Wanna know the biggest stack exchange secret that exist? keep following this text, it will some time start to tell you what it is. Yes really it will you just need to have some faith in this post so that it has the time to explain what it is. It is a real seriouso mather so it needs to take some space. You might be wondering if this is ever gonna tell the secret and the secret says hi, but the biggest stack exchange fora secret still remains a secret. Well, not really any more as i know the secret. Yes indeed I know it, and I want to share it with the world but that would be no fun if it is not a bit of a challenge. And I admire you for already reaching this poin in the text. It is just a little bit further that the real secret will come to light, oh and as a secret hint for you that came this far. I plan to do the secret somewhere here and not on the end, so people that scroll to the end will just read random stuff haha, okay enough fun. Back to the secret of the day. We all know it is a secret and that we should keep it but I really can't. Well I am postin.... Santa is a lie. SO i said it , santa does not exist. its the big secret. congratulations your life just got ruined. And to prevent insta scrollers im just gonna type on some more and hope they dont see the HUGE SO CAPS. oh wait i just did it again. that is no good . how am i going to fix this oh no oh no. btw if you are still reading this. its a waste of time you should not be reading this anymore the secret is spilled. get it, just leave me a cookie and go away. I mean it. Get lost you **</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: -1 for the secret.  Ruined lives.

Comment: @DavidStarkey hence my goal has been achieved

Answer (score 1):

Number Keys using `<kbd>`, `<sub>` and `<sup>` html

<kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd>

above as a quote

> <kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd>
>   <kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd>

above as pre-formatted

```
<kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd>
<kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd>
```

`<sub>` and sup nested in each other in a `<kbd>`

<kbd><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sub>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sub>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            <sup><sub>sub</sub>
                        
                        
                            <sup>sup</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></kbd>

above as preformatted

```
<kbd>
    <sub>
        <sub>
            <sub>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sub>
            <sup>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sup>
        </sub>
        <sup>
            <sub>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sub>
            <sup>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sup>
        </sup>
    </sub>
    <sup>
        <sub>
            <sub>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sub>
            <sup>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sup>
        </sub>
        <sup>
            <sub>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sub>
            <sup>
                <sub>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sub>
                <sup>
                    <sub>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sub>
                    <sup>
                        <sub>
                            sub
                        </sub>
                        <sup>
                            sup
                        </sup>
                    </sup>
                </sup>
            </sup>
        </sup>
    </sup>
</kbd>
```

`<kbd>` inside `<sub>` and `<sup>` within `<kbd>`, uses `&nbsp;` to make `<kbd>` look blocky

Answer (score 0):

[image: HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!! HOSHII MIKI BEST GIRL!!!!!!!]

Comment: ​​​T​​​h​​​i​​​s​​​ ​​​c​​​o​​​m​​​m​​​e​​​n​​​t​​​ ​​​i​​​s​​​ ​​​e​​​x​​​a​​​c​​​t​​​l​​​y​​​ ​​​6​​​0​​​0​​​ ​​​c​​​h​​​a​​​r​​​a​​​c​​​t​​​e​​​r​​​s​​​.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

## Testing delete block of text

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ambition_of_Oda_Nobuna):

> The Ambition of Oda Nobuna (織田信奈の野望?, Oda Nobuna no Yabō) is a Japanese light novel series written by Mikage Kasuga and illustrated by Miyama-Zero. It was adapted into an anime television series that aired from July 9, 2012 to September 24, 2012. Sentai Filmworks licensed the series in 2014 and released the series in December 16, 2014 along with an English dub

Answer (score -2):

> [image]

[image]

[image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: `something something [edit] \[edit\] [randomtext]` something something [edit] \[edit\] [randomtext]

Comment: `[stackoverflow] [so] [se] [anime.se] [anime.so] [cooking.se] [cooking.stackexchange]` [stackoverflow] [so] [se] [anime.se] [anime.so] [cooking.se] [cooking.stackexchange]